# How to extract date from the filename which is in hdf format using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, hdf

I have a file which is in hdf format. I want to extract date from the file name? how can I do that using Python 2.7??

i have tried using split command and also regex but not working

My filename looks like this:

```
CAL_LID_L2_05kmAlay-Standard-V4-20.2012-08-01T06-24-24.hdf
```

Comment: CAL_LID_L2_05kmAlay-Standard-V4-20.2012-08-01T06-24-24.hdf

Comment: please share code and sample input data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) your filename into parts and parse the datetime part from it using [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
fn = "CAL_LID_L2_05kmAlay-Standard-V4-20.2012-08-01T06-24-24.hdf"

import datetime

dt_str = fn.split(".")[-2]  # split out the datetime part

# parse the datetime 
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S")

print(dt_str)
print(dt)
print(dt.date())
```

Output:

```
2012-08-01T06-24-24   # the cutout string
2012-08-01 06:24:24   # the datetime object
2012-08-01            # only the date()
```

Doku:

- [datetime.strptime(string,pattern)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: my filename is CAL_LID_L2_05kmALay-Standard-V4-20.2018-01-04T18-49-46ZN.hdf

Comment: @Sre Why did you leave out the ZN in your code then?!? Use `dt_str = fn.split(".")[-2].rstrip("ZN")`

Comment: now the format is in datetime.data  . Can i add it to a coulmn in excel sheet with dat month year separately

Comment: @Sree why dont you look it up? Tried the documentation already? datetime objects have methods to get year, month, day, hour, minute and second from it:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types